# How to find data with just the year in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to find the count from a table where there are two conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(orderID) AS TotalCount
FROM lineitem
WHERE mode = 'AIR'
AND year(shipdate) = '1998';
```

My problem is because the data type of the column 'shipdate' is DATE, I get an error 'invalid identifier'

How can this be solved?
thanks!

Comment: quote "mode", it's a reserved word. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm

Comment: You can use the below as well where inside the to_char function, column name should come first and then the 'YYYY'

SELECT COUNT(orderID) AS TotalCount
FROM lineitem
WHERE mode = 'AIR'
AND to_char(shipdate,'YYYY') = '1998';

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E

Use `extract`

```
extract(YEAR from shipdate)
```

Comment: Well, yes - EXTRACT it is, but link you posted is related to **MySQL** while the OP uses **Oracle**, so it is kind of useless in that context.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for the help.  Didn't spot that I d used a mysql reference as the syntax is the same... corrected the link in the answer.